# React app not working in Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0. Object.defineProperty Syntax error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, babel-polyfill

My react application is not able to launch in Edge 38.14. The Error I am getting is 
in /app.js

*eval("Object.defineProperty(**webpack_exports**, \"__esModule\", { value: true });\n\n// CONCATENATED* Syntax Error

[image]

I have used "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0" and imported in my index.js file at top.
also i tried using cdn provided by polyfill. but issue remains the same.

Comment: Try copy-pasting the eval'd code from the string into the console to see in which line the syntax error actually is.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi. but didn't get you. what do you mean by copying it. Its a babel compiled code in app.js file. it has no line no.

Comment: That's exactly the problem. Get the contents of the string that is evaled in line 8430, with all its linebreaks, and paste those lines in the console.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi. I did the same and found out that one of the npm module i was using has the issue.

Comment: You might want to [post an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with the solution

Comment: Yes. Found where is the problem. it's in react-s3 npm module. looking for alternative for it.